# iOS SDK 4.1 UIImageView differences?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, ios

I just upgraded to iOS 4.1 SDK and now when I run my app in the simulator one of the images (the only one really) that was working fine before the upgrade is no longer showing up in my view.  I've tried removing the file and re-adding it to the project, cleaning all targets and running a build, and making changes to the XIB where the UIImageView is configured to for it to recompile it, but no dice.  It's worth noting that my Tab-Bar images came through just fine.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If the `UIImageView` is created inside a .xib, open it up in Interface Builder: can you see the image in the "preview"? If not, then it can't find the image to begin with. Perhaps the file has been renamed?

Look inside the application bundle in the Finder. Is your image file present? If not, is it still referenced in your project? Check Xcode to make sure the file name isn't in red (i.e. missing).

Comment: Yes it displays the image just fine in Interface Builder, although when it first loads it shows up as a big question mark.  It's also included in the 'Copy Bundle Resources' step of my target.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they've changed the 4.1 simulator to be (or rather, pretend that the filesystem is) case-sensitive?

Does the app work on a 4.0 device?